# Which event is fired when treeview item loses its focus

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, vsto

I want to know that which event is fired on tree view item when it loses focus.

I am working on Visual Studio tools for office and i want to change background color of tree view item when the focus is moved back to word document

Thanks

Comment: I guess there is some event named LostFocus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `TreeViewItem` loses focus the *`LostFocus`* event is fired. 
Check the documentation here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx